# Fade in/fade out with opacity transition doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, css

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#back-top").hide();

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```
#back-top
{
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#back-top:hover
{
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
```

So here's the problem: when I combine my CSS and jQuery like this the `#back-top` element won't fade in nor fade out when needed to. It would just appear out of nothing at the moment the scroll function triggers without any effects. So if I remove the CSS the fade in/fade out works. How to combine both portions of code so that when the element fades in, it fades only to `opacity: 0.6;` and then stops. When hovered it should have `opacity: 1;` and still being able to fade out when out of the range of the scroll function. I think there must be a CSS only way, with jQuery just adding the classes when the function activates... But I haven't figured it out yet...

Comment: Try using [fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

Comment: A comment to the answers below : you're trying to animate an element with both CSS (transition) and jQuery (fadeIn/out), you have to choose one solution or the other, but never both of them.

Comment: @enguerranws why not? Statistics show that people are more likely to buy something from a fancy looking site.

Comment: I agree with that, I mean : if you wanna do fancy animation, just use CSS transition or JS animation, not both technologies at the same time on same elements. In your example above, this is what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with your assumption that you can just add/remove the class

HTML (For demo)

```
<div style="height: 200vh;">
    <div id="back-top" class="fadeable invisible"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadeable {
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.semi-transparent {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.invisible {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

#back-top {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

#back-top:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#back-top').addClass("semi-transparent");
        $('#back-top').removeClass("invisible");
    } else {
        $('#back-top').removeClass("semi-transparent");
        $('#back-top').addClass("invisible");
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xx5k363n/12/

Comment: And what about `.fadeable`?

Comment: All fadeable does is add the CSS attributes so that it fades instead of instantly switching. The height, width, and background-color is just so that the div shows up

Comment: OK. This kind of worked. All I had to do was comment out the `$('#back-top').hide();` part. But now when I reload the page the button shows up at the top of my website. If I scroll down and then back up it disappears, but still that's not a desired behavior, right?

Comment: Remove `position: fixed` from `.fadeable` and any other styling that. When you scroll down it should appear, and then scroll up it will disappear.

Comment: There is nothing in my code other than the styling under #back-top that would alter the position of the element. It should disappear when you scroll up to within 100px of the top per your question.

Comment: Oh I just added a class with `display: none;` before the function and removed it at `> 100` so now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think fadeTo can help here

https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/pgs9nf0h/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#back-top').fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    } else {
        $('#back-top').fadeTo("fast", 0);
    }
});

$('#back-top').hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    }, function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
});
```

I have attached hover as Jquery function for browser compatability reasons. But still the other answer is way more elegant.

Comment: Uuum... For some reason this didn't work for me. I can see the button fade in and then out and when I scroll down it dissapears?

Comment: Sorry about that. Checking into it.